# JAAS - J2C authentication data

Tags: java, web-applications, websphere, jndi

Any idea of how to read the J2C Authentication Alias (UserId & Password) configured in WAS 7.

This will help me to avoid setting up these credentials as text in xml files in production for security reasons

I got some codes which are not working

com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityConfig securityConfig = com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityConfig.getConfig(); 
    Properties authProperties = securityConfig.getAuthData("widNode/LDAPAuthentication"); 
    String user= authProperties.getProperty("username"); 
    String password= authProperties.getProperty("password");

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access authentication alias from EJB deployed to Websphere 6.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663534/how-to-access-authentication-alias-from-ejb-deployed-to-websphere-6-1)

Answer (score 2):

You can access credentials stored in J2C authentication alias by using DefaultPrincipalMapping JAAS config. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6355992/318054).

Answer (score 1):

You don't typically read that data directly, you attach it to Resource References at deploy time or in the IBM-specific `.xmi` files.

In your web.xml, for the `resource-ref` in-question, use this sub-element to indicate that the J2EE Container will manage the authentication to the resource:

```
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
```

Then, in the WebSphere Administration Console, click on your Enterprise Application, then on the `Resource references` link, then for the particular resource type you should have a configuration block to `Specify authentication method`, where you'll be able to choose from among your defined J2C Aliases.

Alternatively, you can also assign an alias permanently to a Resource rather than to a particular application's use of that Resource. (e.g. assign a particular alias to a particular DataSource). We prefer the former, though, since it doesn't leave a resource automatically accessible to all other applications deployed on the same server.

Comment: That is right and I do appreciate for the response, however my goal is to read & use  the J2C authentication configured alias data like userId and password from my java codes

Comment: Ok. I wouldn't be surprised if that's not actually possible, but I admit I don't know that and have never tried.