# how secure are environment variables in WebSphere

Tags: encryption, websphere

Basically, application needs to makes some external system related e.g. REST API and sFTP  and it requires technical user password to be stored. Currently, it is stored in properties files which is not secured and would like to avoid heavy lifting AES encryption. So would like  to store WebSphere system variable. So what would be the  security applied in WAS. Is it stored as plain text format within WebSphere or does WebSphere applies some kind of encryption?

Comment: WebSphere environment variables are stored as plain text in variables.xml files (location depending on the scope of the variable).

Comment: Why is AES "heavy lifting"? It's not speed I presume. Encrypting them and storing them base 64 encoded may make sense.

Comment: Might find this useful https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mw-1611-lansche-trs/index.html

Comment: Better that WebSphere variables could be J2C authentication alias (at least it will be xor encoded). See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6355992/3701228) how to access such alias from the code -